# Access WiFi Beacons from Android Application

Tags: wi-fi

I was wondering if an android App can have access to the beacon data of the nearby WiFi access points (AP), while the phone is associated with a WiFi AP.

**Note**: I do not want to root the phone or use [startscan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#startScan()) because it is going to be removed in a future release. I skimmed through [WiFi RTT API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-rtt) but it does not seem to provide any other beacon information than RSSI and BSSID.

Thanks for any hints or clues in advance!

Comment: As there are [several such apps available](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admodules#group_955), I'd assume it's possible, yes. Cannot say if each of your details is met, though :)

Comment: @Izzy thanks for your comment. As far as I looked into your link, I only found Bluetooth or BLE scanners. I am interested in WiFi beacons only. WifiManager scanning cannot be triggered using app in a future release, and my guess is that all the WiFi scanning apps use this API and will soon fail. Also I am wondering if it is possible to limit the scanning frequency range.

Comment: Argh, OK – I must have missed the WiFi part and just seen the "Beacon" keyword. Sorry, no idea, I'm no dev…

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for this as well and I found [this thesis submitted in 2015](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/314449537_Flexible_Information_Broadcasting_using_Beacon_Stuffing_in_IEEE_80211_Networks). They were able to get IEs using Android NDK. I still haven't tried it yet. Also if you have found some other solution could share it.

Comment: No I have not found a solutions yet. Thanks for the thesis reference. It is mentioned on page 61 that: "The disadvantage is the problem that currently the extended API is not part of the official Android source (AOSP) and therefore the only possibility using it would be by updating the current Android via Fastboot Mode27 or by replacing the current Android operating system with a version that was built with the changed source"